# Rails 3 readline issue under Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, readline

when I'm trying to run rails console I get an error:

```
C:/ruby/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/completion.rb:9:in `require': cannot load suc
h file -- readline (LoadError)
        from C:/ruby/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/completion.rb:9:in `<top (requir
ed)>'
        from C:/ruby/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/c
ommands/console.rb:3:in `require'
        from C:/ruby/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/c
ommands/console.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/ruby/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/c
ommands.rb:38:in `require'
        from C:/ruby/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/c
ommands.rb:38:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I have installed readline from http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/readline.htm but it didn't help me.

Any suggestions?

Comment: but I'm under Windows not Ubuntu.

Comment: Sorry I missed that bit, a lot of the readline solutions I'm seeing involve reinstalling ruby. Maybe try a fresh re-install using something like [RubyInstaller](http://rubyinstaller.org/).

Comment: It is not a duplicate. It seems that newer versions of RubyInstaller have such a problem with readline. I don't have found a solution for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`readline` is one of the external dependencies that the `ruby stdlib` depends on. The [RubyInstaller](http://rubyinstaller.org/) distribution uses a [pure-ruby implementation](https://github.com/luislavena/rb-readline) of readline in lieu of [GNU-readline](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html).

If you didn't initially install using RubyInstaller I would suggest reinstall using it. It handles all the external dependencies like that for you.

Comment: Reinstalling using RubyInstaller just solved my client's problem. Thanks.